# "Coercing argument of type 'character' to logical" warning message for !any function

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, logical-operators

I run this code to see if in `depth` I have `"0-5cm"`, it works but I also get a warning message that I don't understand, anyone know?

```
if (isTRUE(!any(depth) %in% "0-5cm")) {print("yes")} else {print("no")}
[1] "yes"
Warning message:
In any(depth) : coercing argument of type 'character' to logical
```

Comment: You'll want to use `any` on a logical expression, not on the character vector itself (probably a typo). I.e. `isTRUE(!any(depth %in% "0-5cm"))`. + depending on the exact use case you might not need `isTRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up your parenthesis.
If you want to asses your `if` condition you need something more like:

```
if(!any(depth %in% "0-5cm")) # looking for the many in the specific makes logically little sense, even if it works
```

Also not knowing how `depth` looks like, i assume it is a vector?
If this is the case I'd advise to turn your statement around to:

```
!any("0-5cm" %in% depth) # looking for the specific within the many
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the closing bracket of your `any`. You don't need `isTRUE` since the output of `any` is already logical. Not sure if you're intensionally negating (`!`) `any`.

```
depth <- c(letters, "0-5cm")
[1] "a"     "b"     "c"     "d"     "e"     "f"     "g"    
[8] "h"     "i"     "j"     "k"     "l"     "m"     "n"    
[15] "o"     "p"     "q"     "r"     "s"     "t"     "u"    
[22] "v"     "w"     "x"     "y"     "z"     "0-5cm"

if (any("0-5cm" %in% depth)) {print("yes")} else {print("no")}
[1] "yes"
```